# searching by primary key

Tags: ms-access

I am very new to MS Access. I have created a database `My_database.mdb` with a form that displays some fields. The primary key is a field named `Ticket`.

When I hit the "Search" button, I want to take the numerical value from the Ticket's text field and search for that number in database under 'Ticket' field.

If the number exists, I want to execute some set of instructions, if it does not, I want to execute other set of instructions.

What code should be in the `Command_Click` function?

Comment: Have you looked at the Northwind sample database (nwind.mdb) that ships with all versions of Access? The code is not good, but it is a start.

Answer (score 0):

At first blush, seems this would do the trick:

(I'm assumming "Ticket" is a numeric data type)

```
If Not IsNull(Dlookup("[Ticket]", "[My Table]", "[Ticket] = " & [Ticket].Value)) Then
   'It found the record, so go do something...
   Msgbox "Woo Hoo...I found it!"
Else
   'Didn't find anything, so do something else...
   Msgbox "Nope.  Nada.  Nothing."
End if
```

Replace the above with your table and field reference as applicable.